# MySQL stored procedure using multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can use MySQL stored procedures with one parameter but when I try and use multiple parameters the stored procedure doesn't seam to be called. I will paste the php code I have then the SQL code. Can anyone give any indication why it's not working?

Thanks

```
<?php 

//DB Connection include
include '/connection/proccon.php';    

 $skill=1;
 $level=1;
 $user=1;

//SQL for identify user 
$sqlquestion = sprintf("call updatequestion('%s, %s, %s')", $skill, $user, $level);

echo $sqlquestion;
$resultquestion = mysqli_query($link, $sqlquestion);    

?>
```

SQL Below

```
--Procedure: updatequestion

--DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updatequestion;

DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%' PROCEDURE updatequestion 
(
  IN  v_uid    int,
  IN  v_level  int,
  IN  v_qid    int
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO answer (qid,uid,level) VALUES(v_qid,v_uid,v_level);
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You put quotes around all the parameters, so it's just one string instead of 3 separate parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$sqlquestion = sprintf("call updatequestion(%s, %s, %s)", $skill, $user, $level);
```

The quotes were combining all the parameters into one string.

Comment: Thank you, spent ages on this there is very little online with this notation.

Comment: There are examples of procedures with multiple parameters here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the quotes better, you included 3 parameters into 2 quotes, that's wrong, i think.

Solution:

**

> $sqlquestion = sprintf("call updatequestion(%s, %s, %s)",
>   $skill, $user, $level);

**

Have a nice day